# How do I perform widhu if I'm fasting?

Tags: sawm, wudu

Normally, you need to perform wudu such as rinsing the mouth mouth and inhaling water into nose. Right now i'm fasting, so what should I be careful of? or how should I perform wudu?

I am asking this because everyday when I perform wudu and complete it. I have no water in my mouth and when I start reciting Qur'an, water comes in my mouth.

What should I do with that water, can I drink it or spit it out. If I spit it out, then I can't do it while offering prayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make wudhu the way it's made without swallowing any water.   Also,  don't snuff the water up your nose as this can make the water reach the throat.  Instead, just wash your nose by putting water and without inhaling it.

The Prophet is reported to have said =

> "When you wash your nose, snuff up water unless you are fasting."

(Adab al-Mufrad by Imam al-Bukhari, Sunan Abu Dawud, Jami Tirmidhi)

Comment: Okay, then what about second issue mentioned in question

Comment: It's your saliva, there's no need to spit it.